# Asp.net MVC - Post data to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a sample mvc project in which I am trying to post data to a controller. I have posted sample (see below), but if I add [HttpPost] to method I am getting '404' error.

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.Telerik().NumericTextBox()
                .Name("NumericTextBox")
                .Spinners(false)
                .EmptyMessage("ID")
    %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)
{
    return View();
}

**I also tried,**
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDetails(FormCollection collection)
{
    return View();
}
```

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Customer", action = "GetDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Its quite typical to find where the problem is. Could you please paste the whole code of your view and controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the *Name* to match the parameter on the controller, so I believe it [should be like this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-numerictextbox-introduction.html):

```
Html.Telerik().NumericTextBox()
            .Name("id")
```

Notes:

1. Although you specified UrlParameter.Optional on the `id` route parameter, it's not truly optional unless you make it nullable (ie, `int? id`) in the controller action.
2. Normally you should use GET and not POST for HTTP requests that don't change anything on the server, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: He's doing a test.  In a real app he would be changing the value, so I think it's just confusing to tell him to use Get.  Also, using id for the textbox will conflict with the routed values if a different id is passed on the url.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after matching name of textbox with parameter.

Comment: @CoolArchTek I don't see any other obvious problems.  To confirm: your view above is `GetDetails`, is it?

Comment: Yes. but now it started working once I add another overloaded method without any parameters.
public ActionResult GetDetails()
{
    return View();
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second method, but instead of `FormsCollection`, use:

`GetDetails(int NumericTextBox)`

The parameter must be the same name as the input box.